# Timeframe ="" parameter not contain second time frame

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Currently the parameter timeframe = "" of

```
Indicator(title , overlay , timeframe="")
```

doesn't include seconds time frame.
timeframe parameter only have minutes , hours , weeks and months time frames. But does not include seconds, 1 second , 2 seconds.

How to add seconds to `timeframe =""` parameter .
Or any other parameter we can change with timeframe ="" , to add seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default timeframes are limited.

You can, however, use a user input to get any timeframe you want. Even, the ones that are not listed in that drop down menu.

> The resolution argument allowable values are:
>
> - 1S, 5S, 10S, 15S, 30S - for seconds intervals (chart resolution should be less than or equal to the requested resolution)
> - from 1 to 1440 for minutes
> - from 1D to 365D for days
> - from 1W to 52W for weeks
> - from 1M to 12M for months

Then you need to use the [security()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Context_switching_the_security_function.html) function to get the value from different timeframes.

```
tf = input.string("5S", "Timeframe")
sma_val = ta.sma(close, 9)
sma_mtf = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, tf, sma_val)
```

Comment: Hello thanks for the reply. But if we code as you write we have to set chart time frame same as of indicator time frame. Rigth. I want to set chart time frame into minutes and indicator time frame into seconds. If we can see seconds in timeframe ="" parameter . We can set chart time frame to minutes, hours , weeks , months and set indicator time frame to seconds. That is what ever time frame we set the chart , the indicator shows seconds values.

Comment: You can have multiple `secuirty()` calls if you need to analyze different timeframes. Unfortunately, you cannot have seconds timeframe in that drop-down menu at the moment.